# Convincing meld to ignore specific lines of code?

Tags: regex, fortran, meld

I'm using Meld to spot differences between two similar sets of fortran code. In many cases, the only difference between the two files is an automated version number. This line makes it look like there are more differences than there should be, and it gets confusing.

The automated version number line in question is something like

```
 !! $Id: filename.F90 v#### YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SSx username $
```

Is it possible to convince meld to ignore all lines that look like this line? I don't want meld to ignore all comments, as some differences in comments are important.

Comment: Have a look at preferences/text filters.  You may have to add a new one for SVN.

Comment: The [Meld help page](http://meldmerge.org/help/text-filters.html) indicates that it can filter out regular expressions. Assuming every version control line starts with `!! $Id:`, you can probably easily set it up to ignore those lines.

Comment: I've tried adding '`!! $Id*` and many variants to the list of regular expressions to be ignored in text filters, but to no avail. Is there some specific way I should try to phrase it?

Comment: I believe that `$` is a meta character so it has special meaning to Python. Have you tried `"!! \$Id*"`? (\ inhibits the meta character so as to mean the actual dollar sign).

Comment: Try !! \$Id.*   . means any character, * means repetition

Comment: Hi, it turned out that the trick was to include the final `\$` too. The filter that finally worked was `!! \$.*\$`. 

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 4):

Beware the filter named "All whitespace"

If your regular expression includes a space, e.g. "!! \$Id*" and your expression is after the "All whitespace", then it will never match because all whitespace has already been removed.

To solve this, move your expression before the "All whitespace", expression.

I add this answer because the above comments were correct but did not solve my variation of the problem.

[image]